# Assigning "Lock Computer" to "My Favorites" buttons on Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000, which has five "My Favorites" buttons along the top-center which can be programmed. Using IntelliType Pro (software downloaded from Microsoft), I'd like to set up one of these buttons to perform a "Win+L" to lock my computer.

I know I did this at a past job, but unfortunately I've forgotten how to specify this keypress. Can anyone provide advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this command:

rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation

That should do it.